# How To Upgrade Visual Studio To Use MVC 3 Architecture

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using VS 2010 and I want to use MVC 3 Architecture since i need Razor C# and it is not possible in my Visual studio. Currently it is availing me only MVC 2 so C# Razor is not possible
So how do i upgrade my VS so as to use MVC 3 with Razor C# ?

Comment: Install MVC3 using the Web Platform Installer. Do you use Bing or something?

Comment: @ta.speot.is no i am not using Bing . . . . how or what steps i shoild perform to upgrade my VS or to install MVC 3

Comment: http://bit.ly/15mhtBB

Comment: @ta.speot.is the installation has failed . . . . any other way ?

Comment: Did you get any errors...

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should install asp.mvc 3 to use razor view in asp.net.
you can find it easily on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net). it is an open source.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need to install VS 2010 service pack 1. And Install the MVC 3 framework